# Is it possible to extract mails from Outlook automatically on Mac?

Tags: excel, error-handling, outlook, applescript

I am trying to export mails from Outlook on a Mac using AppleScript as it does not work with VBA. However, I don't progress a lot, the text files are not saved to my Desktop and that's why it always stops with an empty Excel sheet. Any hints?

-- Step 1: Export emails with the Red category to text files
set desktopFolderPath to (path to desktop) as text

tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
set redCategoryName to "Red"

```
set redEmails to {}
set allEmails to every message of inbox
repeat with anEmail in allEmails
    if (subject of anEmail) contains redCategoryName then
        set end of redEmails to anEmail
    end if
end repeat
```

end tell

-- Export emails with the Red category to text files
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
repeat with redEmail in redEmails
set emailSubject to subject of redEmail
set receivedTime to receivedTime of redEmail
set filePath to desktopFolderPath & (my formatReceivedTime(receivedTime) & "_" & emailSubject & ".txt")

```
    set mailBody to content of redEmail
    
    set fileRef to open for access file (POSIX file filePath) with write permission
    write mailBody to fileRef
    close access fileRef
end repeat

display alert "Emails with the Red category have been exported to text files."
```

end tell

-- Step 2: Extract filtered information from text files and write to an Excel file
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
set excelFilePath to desktopFolderPath -- Replace with your desired Excel file path

```
set newWorkbook to make new workbook

tell newWorkbook
    set activeSheet to active sheet
    set rowIndex to 2 -- Start from row 2 for data
    
    set cellValue of range "A1" of activeSheet to "Sender"
    set cellValue of range "B1" of activeSheet to "Email Reference"
    set cellValue of range "C1" of activeSheet to "Names in the Mail"
    set cellValue of range "D1" of activeSheet to "Email Addresses in the Mail"
    set cellValue of range "E1" of activeSheet to "Phone Numbers in the Mail"
    set cellValue of range "F1" of activeSheet to "Date Received"
    
    -- Get the list of text files in the folder
    set textFolderPath to (POSIX file desktopFolderPath) as alias -- Replace with your folder path
    set textFiles to every file of textFolderPath whose name extension is "txt"
    
    -- Loop through each text file and extract filtered information
    repeat with textFile in textFiles
        set filePath to (POSIX path of (textFile as alias))
        set fileContent to read textFile
        
        set senderName to ""
        set emailReference to ""
        set names to ""
        set emailAddresses to ""
        set phoneNumbers to ""
        set dateReceived to ""
        
        -- Extract the desired information from the fileContent
        -- Modify this section to extract the information based on your requirements
        
        -- Write the filtered information to the Excel worksheet
        set cellValue of range ("A" & rowIndex) of activeSheet to senderName
        set cellValue of range ("B" & rowIndex) of activeSheet to emailReference
        set cellValue of range ("C" & rowIndex) of activeSheet to names
        set cellValue of range ("D" & rowIndex) of activeSheet to emailAddresses
        set cellValue of range ("E" & rowIndex) of activeSheet to phoneNumbers
        set cellValue of range ("F" & rowIndex) of activeSheet to dateReceived
        
        set rowIndex to rowIndex + 1 -- Move to the next row for data
    end repeat
    
    save workbook as excelFilePath
    close newWorkbook saving no
end tell

display alert "Filtered information has been written to the Excel file."
```

end tell

-- Helper function to format received time
on formatReceivedTime(receivedTime)
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {" ", "/", ":"}
set receivedTimeItems to text items of (receivedTime as string)
set formattedTime to (item 1 of receivedTimeItems & "-" & item 2 of receivedTimeItems & "-" & item 3 of receivedTimeItems & "_" & item 4 of receivedTimeItems & item 5 of receivedTimeItems & item 6 of receivedTimeItems)
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
return formattedTime
end formatReceivedTime